# XBL doesn't work well on panel?

Tags: firefox-addon, xbl

I have found that the xbl element won't init before it shows up. So when I add an xul box element to panel,and bind it to my xbl ,I can't use like this :box.xblMethod(),FF will throw xblMethod is undefined.
The question is how can I know when I can call the xblMethod? Did any body encount this problem ? Thanks advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find you can do the necessary work in the binding's `<constructor>`.

Comment: here is my code:var xbl=document.createElement('box');
xbl.className='xbl-class-name';
panel.appendChild(con);  When I append the xbl to panel,the <constructor> is not called!

Comment: Is it necessary to call the method immediately? The constructor should be called when the panel is first opened.